# rails changing column default value with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have User model(has_one :profile) and Profile model(belongs_to :user).

I want to change default value of `profile.deliver_project_news` to `:twice_a_week` from `:none if user.user_type != "customer"`.

Can I handle this problem with migration and if it's yes,then how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should not put that logic in your database.  I think it should go in your model layer

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_validate: set_defaults

    def set_defaults
        if user.user_type != "customer"
            deliver_project_news ||= "twice_a_week"
        else
            deliver_project_news ||= "none"
        end
    end
end
```